# Selección de tipo de cliente en checkout woocomerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Lo que quiero hacer es cuando se realice una compra en la tienda es que cuando llegue al checkout haya una opción que permita seleccionar si es cliente natural o distribuidor, pero he consultado casi por todo lado y no encuentro algo al respecto.

Agradezco su ayuda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes añadir un nuevo campo al formulario de checkout que sea un selector o un checkbox que te de a elegir entre las dos opciones. Le das prioridad 1 y asi se pondría el primero. Si necesitas luego enseñar unos campos u otros dependiendo de si ha seleccionado cliente natural o distribuidor, lo puedes hacer mediante javascript escondiendo o enseñando inputs.

Hay varios plugins para editar el formulario de checkout de woocommerce.